# Inner Join rowset from flat file and SQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have TSV file like below.

```
Domain_ID   Domain_URL  Company_Name_1  Company_Type
179238792   sample.com  sample  IT
```

and I have an USQL table like below.

```
Domain_ID   Domain_URL  Company_Name_1
179238792   sample.com  sample
```

I am trying to join both the row-set and trying to get Company_Type for each company.

**Script:**

```
@result = EXTRACT
    Domain_ID int,
    Domain_URL string,
    Company_Name_1 string,
    Company_Type string
    FROM @"sample.txt"
    USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows:1);
@result1=SELECT * FROM table
@result2= @result2= SELECT @result1.Company_Name_1 , @result1.Company_Type FROM @result1
        INNER  JOIN @result ON @result.Domain_ID==@result1.Domain_ID
OUTPUT @result2
            TO "/Mobius_POC/Output/Company_Type.tsv"
            USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

While executing the above script I am getting the following error.

**Error:**

```
Description
Invalid syntax found in the script.
Resolution
Correct the script syntax, using expected token(s) as a guide.
Details

at token '@result2', line 9

near the ###:

**************

_Name_1 string,
    Company_Type string
    FROM @"sample.txt"
    USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows:1);
@result1=SELECT * FROM MobiusPoc.dbo.TLD_AE
 ### @result2= SELECT @result1.Company_Name_1 , @result1.Company_Type FROM @result1
            INNER  JOIN @result ON @result.Domain_ID==@result1.Domain_ID

OUTPUT @resul

Error
E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR
Message
syntax error. Expected one of: '.' ALL ANTISEMIJOIN ANY AS BROADCASTLEFT BROADCASTRIGHT CROSS DISTINCT EXCEPT FROM FULL FULLCROSS GROUP HASH HAVING INDEXLOOKUP INNER INTERSECT JOIN LEFT LOOP MERGE ON OPTION ORDER OUTER OUTER UNION PAIR PARTITION PRESORT PRODUCE READONLY REQUIRED RIGHT SAMPLE SELECT SEMIJOIN SERIAL TO UNIFORM UNION UNIVERSE USING VALUES WHERE WITH ';' '(' ')' ','
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a semicolon (;) missing where the ### are in the error message (before @result2)

```
@result=SELECT * FROM table;
@result2= SELECT @result1.Company_Name_1 , @result1...
```

Comment: Alan you are right. I feel very ashamed on making such a simple syntax error.